# How do I convert a data frame where some rows are duplicates except for one column

Tags: r

I have data on taxpayers which have multiple branches which produces multiple rows which are almost duplicates except for one relevant column (enterprise activity). I want to change this so that each taxpayer has only one row, which involves creating columns 'enterprise_activity_1', 'enterprise_activity_2' and so on.

I realise this is similar to reshaping but I can't think of a way to use tidyr::spread to achieve this.

For simplicity, say we just have a dataframe like:

```r
df <- tibble::tibble(
  TAXPAYER_ID = c(100, 151, 250, 250, 267, 296, 296, 304),
  ENTERPRISE_ACTIVITY = rep(c("AGRICULTURE", "MANUFACTURING"), 4)
)
```

What I would like to achieve is this:

```
TAXPAYER_ID ENTERPRISE_ACTIVITY_1   ENTERPRISE_ACTIVITY_2
100         AGRICULTURE             NA
151         MANUFACTURING           NA
250         AGRICULTURE             MANUFACTURING
267         AGRICULTURE             NA
296         MANUFACTURING           AGRICULTURE
304         MANUFACTURING           NA
```

My actual data has varying numbers of branches per taxpayer so the number of columns should be the maximum number of branches that one taxpayer has.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that question but it's not quite the same as my data does not have a column that provides an index for each branch within a taxpayer. But if I could create that index then I could use tidyr::spread straightforwardly as in that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to group by the taxpayer ID, create a column to handle duplicated identifiers and spread, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(TAXPAYER_ID) %>% 
  mutate(ENTERPRISE_ACT = row_number()) %>% 
  spread(key = ENTERPRISE_ACT, ENTERPRISE_ACTIVITY, sep = '_')

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   TAXPAYER_ID [6]
#  TAXPAYER_ID ENTERPRISE_ACT_1 ENTERPRISE_ACT_2
#        <dbl> <chr>            <chr>           
#1         100 AGRICULTURE      <NA>            
#2         151 MANUFACTURING    <NA>            
#3         250 AGRICULTURE      MANUFACTURING   
#4         267 AGRICULTURE      <NA>            
#5         296 MANUFACTURING    AGRICULTURE     
#6         304 MANUFACTURING    <NA>
```